# What 'access origin' to use in Cordova config.xml for Firebase

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, content-security-policy

I am using the Firebase Realtime Database service. Its subdomain seems to be changing all the time. It seems that currently the only way for me to make it work in config.xml is:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

However, I think this is unsafe as it is susceptible to XSS attacks.

How should I formulate the domain names in the tag? What CSP should I use?

Comment: If only the subdomain changes, using a wildcard like so might be a good start: `<access origin="http://*.firebase-url-that-doesnt-change.com" />` See the [docs here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html)

Comment: Any update on this? Have you had any luck with the approach pointed out in my previous comment?

Comment: I am busy with other stuff at the moment, but I will give it a try when I have the time.